# MySQL sum and grouping extra row

Tags: mysql

If I run the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT username, sum(value) as value 
FROM ztemp 
GROUP BY username
```

I get results with each username and the sum value. However, if do the following query:

```
SELECT username, sum(value) as value 
FROM ztemp
```

Then it gives me the overal sum instead of user by user.

Rather than running two SQL queries to display the result. Is there a way to get both in one SQL query? Or is it better to run the two queries?

Comment: Check out the ```GROUP BY ... WITH ROLLUP``` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a way to do this ... [using the ROLLUP modifier](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

```
GROUP BY username WITH ROLLUP
```

gives the extra row.

Nice, huh?